# INNER JOIN + LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta onde os dados encontram-se em **4 tabelas**:

TAFCBHISTPED = NUPED, DTEMIS

TAFGRPROD = CDGRPR, DSGRPR

TAFPROD = CDPROD, CDGRPR

TAFITHISTPED = NUPED, CDPROD, QTPED

Minha query ficou dessa forma:

```
SELECT
    TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED,
    TAFCBHISTPED.DTEMIS,
    TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR,
    TAFGRPROD.DSGRPR,
    TAFPROD.CDPROD,
    TAFPROD.CDGRPR,
    TAFITHISTPED.NUPED,
    TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD,
    TAFITHISTPED.QTPED
FROM dbo.TAFCBHISTPED
INNER JOIN dbo.TAFITHISTPED ON TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED = TAFITHISTPED.NUPED
LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFPROD ON TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR
```

Porém recebo o seguinte erro:

> SQLState: 42000 Error Code: 4104 Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]O identificador de várias partes "**TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR**" não pode ser associado.

Comment: Ainda não vi como poderia fazer. Poderia me mostrar como?

Comment: Basicamente TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR é chave estrangeira da tabela TAFPROD, TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED e TAFPROD.CDPROD são chaves estrangeiras da tabela TAFITHISTPED.

Comment: Veja se minha resposta te ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou relacionar todas as tabelas, tente o `select` abaixo.

```
SELECT
    TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED,
    TAFCBHISTPED.DTEMIS,
    TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR,
    TAFGRPROD.DSGRPR,
    TAFPROD.CDPROD,
    TAFPROD.CDGRPR,
    TAFITHISTPED.NUPED,
    TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD,
    TAFITHISTPED.QTPED
FROM dbo.TAFCBHISTPED
INNER JOIN dbo.TAFITHISTPED 
   ON TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED = TAFITHISTPED.NUPED
LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFPROD -- Adiciono a relação de TAFITHISTPED com TAFPROD
   ON TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD = TAFPROD.CDPROD
LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFGRPROD -- Aqui incluo a tabela que ficou faltando
  ON TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR
```

Comment: Deu muito certo! Muitissimo obrigado mesmo!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso seja a falta de criar o alias para a sua tabela TAFGRPROD, ou melhor especificar ela junto ao o from.

```
    SELECT
        TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED,
        TAFCBHISTPED.DTEMIS,
        TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR as 'TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR',
        TAFGRPROD.DSGRPR,
        TAFPROD.CDPROD,
        TAFPROD.CDGRPR as 'TAFPROD.CDGRPR',
        TAFITHISTPED.NUPED,
        TAFITHISTPED.CDPROD,
        TAFITHISTPED.QTPED
    FROM dbo.TAFCBHISTPED
    INNER JOIN dbo.TAFITHISTPED ON TAFCBHISTPED.NUPED = TAFITHISTPED.NUPED

-- veja aqui a inclusão da sua tabela.
INNER JOIN dbo.TAFGRPROD ON TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR

    LEFT JOIN dbo.TAFPROD ON TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR = TAFPROD.CDGRPR
```

Comment: Marconcilio o problema é que não foi incluido a tabela TAFGRPROD, trocar o alias de  TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR  para  'TAFGRPROD.CDGRPR' não muda nada

Comment: eu vi isso, mas se ele chamar isso dentro de alguma aplicação também poderia ocorrer erro devido se o mesmo nome da coluna.